# Sumo-gui does not open when running Flow examples

Tags: sumo, flow-project

I have tried to install Flow and SUMO within Ubuntu 16.04 by following the steps listed in the documentation:

https://flow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flow_setup.html

The issue I am facing arises when I reach "Testing your SUMO and Flow installation" and input the following command into the terminal:

`python examples/simulate.py ring`

I believe that the simulation does run, but sumo-gui is failing to open for some reason. 
[image]
The above image shows the inputs I give to the terminal and the output I get from running the aforementioned command. The results are similar whenever I try to run any of the other built-in examples

It should be noted that using the command `sumo-gui` does open up the gui.

Any advice on tackling this issue is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you try adding the --render flag to your command?

Comment: That did the trick! Thank's so much for the quick and simple response, Eugene.